# Does SPSS perform cox regression analysis for time-dependent repeated observations?

Tags: spss, cox-regression, cox

I could not see a source of cox regression for time-dependent REPEAT observations on the Internet. Does spss do this analysis?

Any source suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can find Cox Regression in SPSS under the following menu entry:

```
Analyze -> Survival -> Cox Regression.
```

Comment: Yes, but I have repeated observations like albumin1, albumin2 ,.....albumin8 in this case should I use this menü( Analyze>survival>cox regression) ?